# continuously join a list of strings to the next list of strings

Tags: list, loops, for-loop, join

```
 x = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]

 y = [i + a.pop(0) for i in a] 
 print(y)
```

I want to create a loop that joins each list to the next list so that it looks something like

```
  [[1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,6]]
```

currently what I am getting is

```
  [4, 0, 4, 0], [2, 2, 4, 2]]
```

Comment: This is Python, right?

Comment: Not sure, but i answered it for java :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach with `loop-comprehension` -

```
[x[i]+x[i+1] for i in range(len(x)-1)]
```

Sample runs -

```
>>> x = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
>>> [x[i]+x[i+1] for i in range(len(x)-1)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6]]

>>> x = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10]]
>>> [x[i]+x[i+1] for i in range(len(x)-1)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following data-structure

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>>
```

1. First fill the elements in **`List<ArrayList<Integer>>`**
2. Then start the loop from i=0 and add i+1 elements of  List.get(0)
   and List.get(1) and store in List(0)
3. Repeat the same till n-2. List(n-1) and List(n-2) elements will be
   added together.
4. Remove the last element from the List. (basically n-1 element).

This code should work for you.

```
    List<ArrayList<Integer>> listArray = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>();

    list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2));
    list2.addAll(Arrays.asList(3,4));
    list3.addAll(Arrays.asList(5,6));

    listArray.add(list1);
    listArray.add(list2);
    listArray.add(list3);

    for (int i= 0; i<listArray.size()-1; i++){
        listArray.get(i).addAll(listArray.get(i+1));
    }

    listArray.remove(listArray.size()-1);

    System.out.println(listArray);
```

Output-

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```